# Suggestions on IFFFT Water Level Sensor?

Tags: automation, ifttt, home-automation

I have an IFTTT water valve motor and now I'm looking for a water level sensor. Most of the web has IFTTT water leak detectors, but I need a submersible sensor that triggers if water is NOT detected. The use for this is to refill my hot tub so it doesn't get too low, empty and freeze, on my remote property where I can't get to often.

Comment: You are looking for a ready-to-use product, or you want to develop such thing yourself. In the first case, your question is off-topic. In the second case, you should do your research first and decide which platform you want to use. An esp8266 (nodemcu) and any suitable phisycal water level sensor can do the job.

Comment: As the idea is quite the same with a simple water level sensor, you could start here: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/door-status-monitor-using-the-esp8266/,

Comment: On the other hand, if you need frost prevention, you should not rely on such a roundtrip. IMHO this is a quite _local_ task, and kinda critical from a technical point of view, where using IFTTT could introduce a risk. This application should work even if no internet is available.ó for any reason. Notifying you should be a side-effect.

Comment: I've got my own IFTTT water valve motor, linked to the SmartLife app and platform, so this isn't a ready made solution but DIY. The app and the cloud account allow you to create actions (i.e. low water) to trigger a device (i.e. turn valve on). Thanks, the ESP8266 could do the trick, I'll have to go that route if I can't find a Water Level or submersible Water Sensor device.

Comment: Also agree on locality, little concerned with the cloud essentially as the controller. I do have backup to just drain the hot tub, so this isn't a critical app. But I don't want my backup person to have to top it off as much as the devices can. But that's got me thinking, I might build something that if it goes offline, it opens the drain valve automatically. Putting me on the safe side.